# How to send a POST in UWP c#

Tags: c#, post, uwp, iot

I need to send a POST method but it says invalid JSON content, do somebody knows what im doing wrong in the JSON format ¿?, ill apreciate a lot.

```
Uri resourceAddress;
        if (!Helpers.TryGetUri(pcHost + pcPort + "/api/code/scan", out resourceAddress))
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Invalid URI.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            terminalRef = "1";
            //code = "Uc0E17G4nW";
            IHttpContent jsonContent = new HttpJsonContent(JsonValue.Parse("{\"code\":\"" + code +
                                                                            ",\"ref\" : \""+ terminalRef +
                                                                            "\"}"));





            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, jsonContent).AsTask(cts.Token);
            Debug.WriteLine(".");
            //await Helpers.DisplayTextResultAsync(response, cts.Token);
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Completed", NotifyType.StatusMessage);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Error: " + ex.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            String errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Im sending a String parameter to the function.

Comment: So, the question really has nothing to do with sending a POST and everything to do with parsing text to JSON. You really ought to start by using `String.Format` or string interpolation rather than string concatenation. It makes constructing such a string easier and more readable and thus less error-prone. I don't know whether that is your issue but it's a good idea either way. Of course, you also need to actually look at - and thus show us - what the result of that string constriction is. Looking at the code that builds something is no substitute for looking at what it built.

Comment: not sure where HttpJsonContent came from unless you wrote it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.IHttpContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple failures i found how to make it works ( at least for me) hope it can help people working with Windows 10 iot in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) i know how difficult can be to fin proper documentation.

```
              Uri resourceAddress;

            if (!Helpers.TryGetUri(Host + Port + "/XXX/YYY/directory", out resourceAddress))
            {
                return;
            }

            IHttpContent jsonContentCoordinates = new HttpJsonContent(JsonValue.Parse("{\"zzz\": \"" + something
                                                                              + "\", \"xxx\": \"" + somethingXXX
                                                                              + "\",\"yyy\": \"" + somethingYYY
                                                                              + "\" }"));
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseCoordinates = new HttpResponseMessage();
            string httpResponseBodyCoordinates = "";
            try
            {
                httpResponseCoordinates = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, jsonContentCoordinates).AsTask(cts.Token);
                httpResponseBodyCoordinates = await httpResponseCoordinates.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                httpResponseCoordinates.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                FlagInternetNotConnected = false;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
             //Catch it if it fails.

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Noted that your string is not correctly formatted. Can you try the parsing below string,

```
"{\"code\" : \"" + code + "\", \"ref\" : \"" + terminalRef + "\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way was as the Jaliya Udagedara's suggestion, you would need to check your json string's [format](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) to make sure that it's correct.

Another a simple way is using the [Newtownsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to convert a c# object.

For example:

```
string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {code="code", Ref = "terminalRef" });
IHttpContent jsonContent = new HttpStringContent(jsonstring, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, jsonContent).AsTask(cts.Token);
```